# sessions arent working on sinatra

Tags: ruby, session, cookies, sinatra

So i've been using sinatra and well no matter what i try i cannot seem to get sessions to work as intended.

Im enabling session/cookies with the following:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'localhost_tester',
                             :path => '/',
                             :expire_after => 14400, # In seconds
                             :secret => 'secret_stuff'
```

And im trying to create a login page, the post data seems to be getting sent but no session is being created. This is what im using:

```
get '/account-login' do
  @title = 'Adnetwork'
  erb :accounts
end

post '/account-login' do

  email = params[:email]
  password = params[:password]

  user = User.new()

  if user.login(email, password)

    #session isnt being made...
    session['email'] = email

    #redirect once session is complete
    redirect to'/dashboard'
  else
    erb :accounts
  end

end
```

The session wont actually be called "email" thats just an example i was using while testing. But it never actually creates the session. I have cookie editor plugin on chrome to see whats happening and the only thing thats being created is a session called "localhost" tester.

Am i being an idiot and doing it all wrong or is it something else that im missing?

Comment: Have you tried reading the session from the server? It should be encrypted so the client can't read it.

Comment: have you put `enable :sessions` to your main router/controller/app script?